# case statement creating X field and where clause X field in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, case, where-clause

Table data and structure:

```
Name     DateOfBirth
Thuso      1987-02-27 00:00:00.000
Sue        1968-02-27 00:00:00.000
Zee        1999-02-27 00:00:00.000
```

Query:

```
USE [PersonDatabase]
GO

DECLARE @AGE int  =1
Select Name, X=CASE
   WHEN( ( year(getdate()) - year(DateOfBirth)) >=0 AND (year(getdate()) - year(DateOfBirth)) <=17) THEN 1
   WHEN( ( year(getdate()) - year(DateOfBirth)) >= 18 AND (year(getdate()) - year(DateOfBirth)) <=29) THEN 2
   WHEN( ( year(getdate()) - year(DateOfBirth)) >= 30 AND (year(getdate()) - year(DateOfBirth)) <=60) THEN 3
END
froM PersonDatabase.mem.Namebirth
WHERE (X=@AGE)
```

it produces the Output am not expecting as:

```
X
1
2
3
```

MY Question is : Where do I go wrong in my `WHERE` CLAUSE of the query,for it to produce the output as:

```
X
1
```

Answer (score 3):

I see two ways of fixing your query :

```
DECLARE @AGE int  =1
Select Name, CASE
   WHEN( ( year(getdate()) - year(DateOfBirth)) >=0 AND (year(getdate()) - year(DateOfBirth)) <=17) THEN 1
   WHEN( ( year(getdate()) - year(DateOfBirth)) >= 18 AND (year(getdate()) - year(DateOfBirth)) <=29) THEN 2
   WHEN( ( year(getdate()) - year(DateOfBirth)) >= 30 AND (year(getdate()) - year(DateOfBirth)) <=60) THEN 3
END
froM PersonDatabase.mem.Namebirth
WHERE 
CASE
       WHEN( ( year(getdate()) - year(DateOfBirth)) >=0 AND (year(getdate()) - year(DateOfBirth)) <=17) THEN 1
       WHEN( ( year(getdate()) - year(DateOfBirth)) >= 18 AND (year(getdate()) - year(DateOfBirth)) <=29) THEN 2
       WHEN( ( year(getdate()) - year(DateOfBirth)) >= 30 AND (year(getdate()) - year(DateOfBirth)) <=60) THEN 3
    END = @AGE
```

OR

```
SELECT Name, X FROM(
  Select Name, X=CASE
     WHEN( ( year(getdate()) - year(DateOfBirth)) >=0 AND (year(getdate()) - year(DateOfBirth)) <=17) THEN 1
     WHEN( ( year(getdate()) - year(DateOfBirth)) >= 18 AND (year(getdate()) - year(DateOfBirth)) <=29) THEN 2
     WHEN( ( year(getdate()) - year(DateOfBirth)) >= 30 AND (year(getdate()) - year(DateOfBirth)) <=60) THEN 3
  END
  froM PersonDatabase.mem.Namebirth
) T
WHERE (T.X=@AGE)
```

Comment: Ahaaa ! Thanx a million times Thomas,This is what I was looking for.